# In a ggplot2 geom_tile plot, is it possible to dodge the positions of tiles?

Tags: r, position, ggplot2

I'm trying to produce a bar plot where the bars fade vertically according to a third variable, and I'm using geom_tile to enable this. However, I have multiple bars for a given category on the x-axis, and I'd like to dodge their positions to put alike x values together in groups of bars which don't overlap.

Is it possible to use `position='dodge'` or similar with `geom_tile` and, if so, what's wrong with my syntax?

```
a <- data.frame(x = factor(c(rep('a',5), rep('a',5), rep('b',5), rep('c',5))),
                y = c(1:5, 1:5, 1:5, 1:5),
                z = c(5:1, c(5,4,4,4,1), 5:1, 5:1)
                )

ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, group = x)) +
  geom_tile(aes(alpha = z, fill = x, width = 1),
            position = 'dodge')
```

The example data frame `a` looks like this:

```
x y z
1  a 1 5
2  a 2 4
3  a 3 3
4  a 4 2
5  a 5 1
6  a 1 5
7  a 2 4
8  a 3 4
9  a 4 4
10 a 5 1
11 b 1 5
12 b 2 4
13 b 3 3
14 b 4 2
15 b 5 1
16 c 1 5
17 c 2 4
18 c 3 3
19 c 4 2
20 c 5 1
```

...and the resulting graph from the current code has no gaps between the x values, and the two where x is a are drawn on top of one-another:

[image]

I want those two bars where x is 'a' to be drawn as separate bars.

This is a mock-up of what I want the result to look like. The data are not correct for either of the a columns but it shows the grouping on the x-axis which is desired:

[image]

Comment: What exactly does your desired output look like? Something like this? `ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, group = x)) + geom_bar(aes(alpha = z, fill = x, width = 0.5) position = 'dodge', stat = "identity")`

Comment: Very similar to your example code, but with the two 'a' bars adjacent rather than superposed!

Comment: Then, `ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=x, alpha=factor(z))) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")` ?

Comment: No. :) The graph should look very similar to my example above, except there should be two columns for a, one column for b and one column for c, rather than just one for each, instead of the two a columns being plotted on top of one-another.

Comment: Can you draw by hand and upload it?

Comment: I've added an example at the bottom of the question above!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 2**

To get your desired effect, use `geom_bar()` but be sure to change the `y` data to indicate the bar height, in this case 1.  The reason is that the bars get stacked, so there is no need to specify the y-axis **position**, but instead specify the **height**.

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- data.frame(x = factor(c(rep('a',5), rep('a',5), rep('b',5), rep('c',5))),
                y = 1,
                z = c(5:1, c(5,4,4,4,1), 5:1, 5:1)
)

a$bar <- rep(1:4, each=5)

ggplot(a, aes(x = factor(bar), y=y, fill=x, alpha=z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_grid(~x, space="free", scale="free")
```

You should get:

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

You can get close to what you describe by:

- Explicitly adding another column that differentiates different bars in the same category
- Using faceting

For example:

```
a$bar <- rep(1:4, each=5)

ggplot(a, aes(x = factor(bar), y = y, fill=x, alpha=z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  facet_grid(~x, space="free", scale="free")
```

[image]

---

**ORIGINAL**

You can use `geom_bar()` for this, by using `stat="identity"`:

```
ggplot(a, aes(x = x, y = y, fill=x, alpha=z)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: It's great that you can do this with `geom_bar`, but it doesn't solve my main issue--the two a bars are still plotted over the top of one another, rather than adjacent.

Comment: @Statto OK, I get it.  How about using faceting, as I show in my edited answer?

Comment: There is one weird thing about this: why, in the right-hand bar in the a facet, do the three '4' values have slightly different opacities?

Comment: @Statto Optical illusion? If I cover the bar with two sheets of paper, they look identical.

Comment: It's definitely not an optical illusion! The 4th box from the bottom in that column, ie 5,4,4,_4_,1 is definitely much less opaque than the third! I can see the underlying grid through it.

Comment: The bars are overlapped, that is, the area of the 4th from the bottom is drawn twice (for y = 4 and y = 5), while the area of the 3rd is drawn three times (for y = 3, 4, and 5).

Comment: As @kohske points out, there was some overplotting.  I edited my answer to show how to remedy this.